# Unable to retrieve response data from python requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I had tried to get the response data from a website https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/49784960 using python requests.
But am not getting the response and i had tried selenium too. But still the error persists

Using Python requests

```
import requests


session=requests.session()
response=session.get('https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/49784960')
print(response.text)
```

Using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/49784960")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Is there any thing am missing? For python requests, i has passed headers also.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: This is the error "MSCdirect.com is currently not available for your use."

Comment: I tried it a couple of times and couldn't replicate the error.

Comment: Are you able to get the response text

Comment: Yes, I did, but because I was using requests, the response it isn't what you're looking for - the page is dynamically loaded using jscript and requests can't handle it. Didn't try it using selenium, though.